# Unable to update Now Playing tile on music playback in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio-player

I'm trying to build a music player app in Windows Phone 7. Adding items to history page of the Music+Videos app is working fine. But, when trying to associate the "Now Playing" tile so that it opens my app when it is clicked (or via volume music controls), it throws an exception.

Working code (only history):

```
if (currentsong != null)
        {
            MediaHistoryItem historyItem = new MediaHistoryItem();
            historyItem.Title = currentsong.Name;
            historyItem.Source = "";
            historyItem.ImageStream = currentsong.Album.GetAlbumArt();

            if (historyItem.ImageStream == null)
            {
                StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("noalbum2.png", UriKind.Relative));
                historyItem.ImageStream = sri.Stream;
            }

            MediaHistory mediaHistory = MediaHistory.Instance;
            mediaHistory.WriteRecentPlay(historyItem); //WORKS
            mediaHistory.NowPlaying = historyItem;   //Throws exception
        }
```

The exception generated is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.dll
>
> Additional information: partial read?

Please help.

Thanks,
Siddhant

Comment: Well, I have noticed that if I call the (or put) the MediaHistory code in the AudioPlayer (class in the bacnkground Agent), then it doesn't work. And if I put the code in the event handlers (e.g. something_PlayStateChanged), the error doesn't appear. However, the RecentPlay and NowPlaying are not updated in the background.

Comment: I haven't tried this using background agent. I applied this when a song is played or next/previous controls are used.